# Is it "after 9-hour drive" or "after 9 hour drive"?

Tags: punctuation

The sentence is: "I arrived NYC after 9 hour drive." What is the appropriate way to punctuate 9 hour? and whether it is "x-hour" vs "x-hours" or "x hour"?

(possible wrong tags)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be "I arrived [in] NYC after [a] 9-hour drive."

Note that some stylesheets (AP, for example) require numbers under 11 to be spelled out: "I arrived in NYC after a nine-hour drive."

Comment: Note that the indefinite article *a* is actually required here.

Comment: @JSBangs: I put the brackets around *in* and *a* not to mark them as optional, but to emphasize that I was including them in the OP's sentence, which I was quoting.

Comment: @Robusto, I understood your intention. I was just clarifying for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @JSBangs: Ah, sorry for the intrusion then. A lot of people here are programmers and I worried that the brackets, which are used in documentation to indicate optional arguments to function signatures and the like, might be throwing people off.

Comment: @Robusto - Maybe it's just me, but I wouldn't have included the hyphen. Is this a British vs. American difference?

Comment: @ssakl: Not sure about British, but in American English one is expected to hyphenate compound adjectives.

Comment: @Robusto - I'm an American, and I find this odd. Although it could be that the hyphen is being dropped in informal usage (IME) in the same way that email lost its hyphen a few years back. Formally, you are, of course, correct. At least until folks get tired of typing hyphens... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Compound adjectives are usually hyphenated. Thus, in this case, you should place a hyphen between *nine* and *hour*:

> I arrived NYC after a nine-hour drive.

In reality, this hyphen is often dropped in compound adjectives involving number measurements, especially when the number is not written in words. Thus, one would be more likely to see *9 hour drive* than *9-hour drive*. However, it's never *9 hours drive*. Thus:

> - I arrived NYC after a 9-hour drive.
> - I arrived NYC after driving for 9 hours.

Personally, I would always opt to write the number in words, for consistency's sake.